# toggle element from other form element (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have two form's elements: checkboxes and drop-down list. Checkbox value is link with drop-down list by id (option id=checkbox val) The option list should be hide by default. After checkbox is checked I want to show specific options from the list. Unfortunately it doesn;t work properly.
My code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Hourly">Hourly
<input  type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Daily">Daily
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Weekly">Weekly
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Monthly">Monthly
<input  type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Yearly">Yearly
<br>
<select  multiple="multiple">
  <option  id="Hourly">Hourly</option>
  <option id="Weekly">Weekly</option>
  <option id="Daily">Daily</option>
  <option id="Monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option id="Yearly">Yearly</option>
</select>
<div></div>
<script>
  $( "input[type='checkbox']"  ).change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( $( "input:checked" ) ).each(function() {
      str = $( this ).val();
    });
    $( "option[id=" + str + "]" ).toggle();
  })
  .change();
</script>
```

Any ideas what to improve?

Comment: `$( $( "input:checked" ) )` what is this?

Comment: You can't hide and show options, at least not cross-browser

Comment: Also `str = $(this).val();` would return true or false, so not what you need.

Comment: @u_mulder I belived it works like: for each checked element do ... @ adeneo should I hide select ?

Comment: @Dura I don't agree. You retrive value of current (this) element and pass it to the variable.

Comment: @arth81 Absolutely, but what is the current element and what does it return?